# "Use of unresolved identifier" error, yet I have the identifier declared in a framework

Tags: objective-c, swift

The errors come up in this method:

```
func stringFromProduct(product: SPTProduct) -> String {
    switch product {
    case SPTProductFree:
        return "Free"
    case SPTProductPremium:
        return "Premium"
    case SPTProductUnlimited:
        return "Unlimited"
    default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}
```

They show up at SPTProductFree, SPTProductPremium, and SPTProductUnlimited.

Yet, in a header file of a framework I am using, this is declared:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, SPTProduct) {
    SPTProductFree,
    SPTProductUnlimited,
    SPTProductPremium,
    SPTProductUnknown
};
```

My bridging file is set up correctly, but it still says it is an unresolved identifier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference:

> Swift imports any C enumeration marked with the `NS_ENUM` macro as a Swift enumeration with an `Int` raw value type. The prefixes to C enumeration case names are removed when they are imported into Swift, whether they’re defined in system frameworks or in custom code.

So your Objective-C enumeration is imported to Swift as

```
public enum SPTProduct : UInt {
    case Free
    case Unlimited
    case Premium
    case Unknown
}
```

and you can see that by using the "Generated Interface" menu item
on the Objective-C header file containing the definition.

Consequently, you use it from Swift as

```
func stringFromProduct(product: SPTProduct) -> String {
    switch product {
    case .Free:
        return "Free"
    case .Premium:
        return "Premium"
    case .Unlimited:
        return "Unlimited"
    default:
        return "Unknown"
    }
}
```